Can I safely "home" a 24BYJ28 geared stepper by ramming it into the limit?
I am building a toolchanger for my 3D printer and I want to use a 24BYJ28 geared stepper motor for the tool changer.
When I power up the machine, the machine doesn't know the current position of the stepper.
With ungeared steppers I can just move it into the limit, letting it skip steps until I know that it reached the limit.
Can I do the same with a 24BYJ28 or will this destroy the nylon gears inside?

why not use a home sensor? ... the question about the motor gears should be put to the manufacturer ... besides, it is a mechanical engineering question, not an electronics design question

There's no space for a homing sensor there. I'm adapting the E3D toolchanger.

According to the specifications, the friction torque (that required to spin an unpowered motor from the output) is 60 to 120 mN.m
The implication of providing that specification at all is that you can back-drive the motor without damage. I have indeed back-driven one experimentally by hand without (warning - sample size of 1) apparently damaging it.
The rated output torque is 34 mN.m, rather less than the above friction torque.
Taken together, they seem to imply that the gear box is strong enough to stall the driven motor without damage.
With my project, I intend to do exactly what you want to, home the motor by stalling it into an end-stop. However, being a cautious soul, I will reduce the drive during homing to the minimum necessary to just move the motor, to minimise gearbox loading.

Nice, thanks! That's exactly what I needed to know!
